# If $K/k$ is a one-dimensional function field and $D\in \operatorname{Der}_k(K)\setminus\{0\}$, is it true that $\ker D=k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a one-dimensional function field over a characteristic zero field $k$. I.e., $K$ is a finite extension of $k(x)$. We know how to calculate $\Omega_{k[x]/k}\cong k[x]dx$, and the module of Kahler differentials is invariant under localization and finite extensions. This implies that $\Omega_{K/k}\cong Kdx$ and so $\operatorname{Der}_k(K)=\Omega_{K/k}^\vee$ is a one-dimensional $K$-vector space.

If $D\in \operatorname{Der}_k(K)\setminus\{0\}$, then clearly $k\subset \ker D$ for $D$ is $k$-linear. I'm pretty sure that we have an equality there. This is true for $K=k(x)$ since it holds for $D=d/dx$ and any other derivation is a multiple of this one. Nevertheless, I'm a little confused about this maybe being affected by the finite extension.

I would appreciate any clarifications.

Comment: Do you mean that your derivation is also $K$-valued? If so, shouldn’t elements in $K$ algebraic over $k$ also be in the kernel of such a derivation? This seems to be the only obstruction: the kernel of $D$ should be a $k$-subfield of $K$, separably closed in $K$ – so if it contains a transcendental element and $k$ has characteristic zero, it is all of $K$.

Comment: I do mean that the derivation is $K$-valued. Can you explain more why this is the only obstruction? (The result is true if $k$ is algebraically closed, for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer with a little bit more detail.

Let $D: K \rightarrow K$ be a nonzero $k$-derivation.

Let $F=\{z \in K,\, Dz=0\}$ be the kernel of $D$. Clearly $k \subset F$ and $F$ is a $k$-vector subspace. Moreover, let $u,v \in F$, then $D(uv)=uD(v)+vD(u)=0$ so $F$ is stable under product. Similarly, if $u=vw$ with $v \neq 0$ and $u,v \in F$, then $vD(w)=D(u)-wD(v)=0$. So $F$ is a $k$-subfield of $K$.

Moreover, let $P \in F[t]$ be an irreducible (thus separable) polynomial. For any $u \in K$, it’s easy to see that $D(P(u))=P’(u)D(u)$. So if $P(u)=0$, then $P’(u)\neq 0$ so $D(u)=0$. Thus $F$ is algebraically closed in $K$.

Now, because $K$ is algebraic over some $k(t)$, it has exactly two $k$-subfields which are algebraically closed in $K$: the algebraic closure of $k$ in $K$ or $K$ itself.

Since $D\neq 0$, $F$ can’t be $K$, so $F$ must be the algebraic closure of $k$ in $K$.

In particular, if $k$ is algebraically closed, or $K$ is the field of functions of a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over $k$, then $F=k$.

Comment: Wonderful answer @Aphelli. May I ask how you conclude the result if $K$ is the field of functions of a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over $k$? (In particular, how smoothness and properness enter in the reasoning?)

Comment: Proper/smooth doesn’t actually matter – in characteristic zero, a $k$-field finite over $k(T)$ is always the function field of a smooth proper curve. The important part is *geometrically connected*. Indeed, let $X$ be the smooth proper curve associated with $k$. Then every stalk ring is normal, so an element of $K$ algebraic over $k$ is defined everywhere, hence is in $O(X)$. To conclude, we just need to show that $O(X)=k$. If $X$ is geometrically connected, let $k’$ be the algebraic closure of $k$, we just need to show that $O(X_{k’})=k’$. But the LHS is finite reduced connected over $k’$.

Comment: but then this proves the statement in the generality that I asked, isn't it?

Comment: I’m not sure about what your exact setting is – if $k$ is algebraically closed, yes, but if, say, $K$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)(T)$ and $k=\mathbb{Q}$, then no. The kernel of a nonzero $K$-valued $k$-derivative is exactly the set of elements of $K$ algebraic over $k$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Now I get it. The field $K$ from your last comment is the function field of a smooth projective curve, but not the function field of such a curve that's also geometrically connected.